# Submit iOS Build to Facebook from Xamarin.Form

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin.forms

I made a Cross platform app using xamarin form , I uploaded the android version to Facebook review team and I need to do the same for the iOS version, the instructions says you need to zip the file by using:

```
ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent `ls -1 -d -t ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/*.app | head -n 1` path/to/YourApp.zip
```

to zip the build found in Xcode derived data , anyway my Xcode derived data doesn't contains the Build folder(that's because I am using Xamarin?) referred in the comand line, what i have to do? I didn't found any tutorial to achieve this in xamarin form.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code above wants to compress a set of .app files. You could find the files under `Xcode/DerivedData` if you use XCode to build the project. But if you use Xamarin to develop applications, there won't be corresponding files in the folder.

However, you can find the files in the path: `YourProjectPath/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug`. Then at last, you could make the .zip file using the path above.

Comment: Thank you so much , I'll try ;)

Comment: Unfortunally, no because I'm having trouble making the zip file with that command line. Have you got like a guide or something?

Comment: @GiulioSerra We can only refer to the documentation of Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced/. And did it help you to find the .app files?

Comment: For now I'm leaving the facebook integration alone, when I'll have any update I'll let you know, It's even hard to reach out to someone on the developer page so I'm leaving it for now.